# BouncyCastle Error

Tags: android, encryption, bouncycastle, private-key

I am developing an android application. In this application I create my own private key by passing pass phrase, user id and keys. When creating the private key, it says "Error: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: cannot create cipher: CAST5/CFB/NoPadding"

I have checked the logcat as well as the warning section in the Eclipse but there is error there. SO why I am getting this error and how to solve it.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am using bcpg-jdk15on-150.jar and bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar,

which I have downloaded from http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

**EDIT**

the solution of renaming one or both the jar files does not work. When I run the application it says Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/bouncycastle/apache/bzip2/BZip2Constants; 
and Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/bouncycastle/apache/bzip2/BZip2Constants;
I think there is a problem with the duplication of some files within the two jar files. Can anyone suggest me a solution regarding this?

Thanks

Comment: [SpongyCastle](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/)

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use latest BouncyCastle and setup security in your code in the following way:

```
    Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```

It sets Bouncy Castle library as preferred security provider; Android's default provider config has BC at position 3 so this code will remove it and insert BC again at position 1.
It solved the problem for me.

Comment: as @Tomasz Hadam explain for eg using BC v1.61 remove the "inbuild" BC and insert your gradle/jar BC version at position 1